# How to export WSO2 API Information

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can you export API information such as subscribed users, endpoints, gateway information from WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 in order to compile documentation for API's that are published?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the basic information of the API, swagger definition, Documents, and the sequences available for the API using the **API import/export tool** [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems to be more for exporting it as an artifact to deploy into another Publisher, I'm looking to capture the information such as the swagger doc, endpoints etc in order to document whats already published

Comment: Exporting an API with all the metainformation and docs has been introduced from APIM 3.1.0. It is not supported in 2.1.0.